# Which button was clicked among a same class of buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

Okay, I have some code like this:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $idx = $i;
?>
<input class="edit-btn" type="button" name="edit" value="" onClick="editMe(this)"/>
<?php } ?>
```

My problem is: in function editMe() (in javascript) how can I determine which button was clicked (according to $idx value)? Actually I don't like to set $idx as id of buttons and also I don't like to use $idx as their values.

**Update**: i -> $i, I want to emphasize that each button should associate to an unique index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the value of idx as second parameter to the function

Not sure about PHP syntax

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $idx = $i;
?>
<input class="edit-btn" type="button" name="edit" value="" onClick="editMe(this, <?php echo $idx; ?>)"/>
<?php } ?>
```

then

```
function editMe(el, idx){
}
```

Comment: When the loop finishes execution, `$idx` will hold the value of the *last* iteration, which means, it will contain `19`. If the OP needs to create multiple buttons, then the `<input` block needs to be *inside* the loop. Also, as you stated in the answer, the PHP syntax is incorrect. To use variables from the PHP-context, you'll need to add them inside a  `<?php ... ?>` block.

Comment: @duong_dajgja it will be that... because we are using it only used to create the markup.... did you check the generated html and tested the functionality

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Okay, you're right. I tried your idea, it worked well. Thank you!
I removed my comment that agreed with AmalMurali